# TPT Inheritance in EF Core Power Tools

Tags: entity-framework-core, ef-power-tools

I have a project which I am porting from EF6 to EF Core v7, and I'm using EF Core Power Tools to reverse engineer the model classes from the database. I want to reuses as much of my old code as I can so I want the new classes to match the EF6 ones.

The EF6 model uses TPT inheritance but when I used Power Tools in import the base and derived tables I get two classes with navigation properties. I cannot see any way to identify there is an inheritance relationship between them.

Is this even possible with Power Tools? If not, is there a way I can create my EF model with inheritance without having to do it by hand (it is a huge database!)